# Django - what is the best way to avoid doing repetitive queries in a dynamic navbar?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently developing a project which has two apps. When the user logs into the system, the navbar will show the links according to what permissions the user has in the database.

If the user only has permissions for app 1, the links it will show will only correspond to this app, the same if it only has permission for app2. If the user has permission for both the navbar will show all the links of both apps.

Being dynamic the navbar has to make queries to the database. so I want to avoid making a query every time a page is loaded.

I have thought that an option is, in the view, to make the query a first time and then store it with request.session:

```
Try:  #If the query has already been made, it accesses the saved value
  query = request.session['navbar']
Except: # If the query has not been made, makes it and saves it in request.session['navbar'] 
  request.session['navbar'] = #QUERYCODE
```

This is a good way to handle the problem? is there another better way?

Comment: If you really need this optimization at this point, you could maybe use a @cached_property and put your logic for determining if the user has access in there.

Comment: is there any problem with the request.session approach?